# Endpoint not working with flask-selenium on render.com?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask, render.com

Code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/t")
def st():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get("http://www.example.com")
    button = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
    button.click()
    bpt = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "p").text
    browser.quit()
    return bpt
```

when the route is "/" it works fine but when its /anything it gives a 502 error??
FYI adding this

```py
@app.route("/hello")
def sy():
    return "hello"
```

works so if i go to /hello it will return hello no errors its just when im using selenium with an endpoint thats not the default "/"
this code does also work locally.
build command: gunicorn main:app